# java form connections

Tags: java, forms, connection

hi i am new to Java i developed many forms but i am unable to connect those forms please any one tell me how can connect one form to another form for example after login screen my application form should be open

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're coming from a Visual Basic background and you are trying to have some kind of procedure to display a login window, then a main program window.

There are many different ways to do this, but the two most common would be:

```
Display login dialog
Retrieve login information from closed dialog
Validate or exit/redisplay login
Display main window
```

and

```
Display login window
On 'OK' being pressed, validate or exit/display error
Hide self
Show main window
```

The first would be implemented something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginDialog dlg = new LoginDialog();
    dlg.setVisible(true);
    LoginCredentials cred = dlg.getCredentials();
    if ( ! valid(cred)) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow(cred);
    wnd.setVisible(true);
}
```

The second would look more like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginWindow app = new LoginWindow();
    app.setVisible(true);
}

LoginWindow.actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ( ! validCredentials()) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
    MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
    wnd.setVisible(true);
}
```

I recommend the first, so you can reuse the `LoginDialog` in other places, as it does not start the main window of this specific application itself.